# Tag SQlAlchemy Model as dataclass

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to figure out how to use typehints properly with sqlalchemy.
I have 2 Models:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

```py
class Person(Base):
    __table__ = "persons"

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Column(String, nullable=False)
    age: str | None = Column(String)
    pets: list[Animal] = relationship(
        "Animal",
        back_populates="persons",
        lazy="selectin",
    )

class Animal(Base):
    __table__ = "animals"

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    weight: float | None = Column(Float)
    max_age: int | None = Column(Integer)
    owner: Person = relationship(
        "Person",
        back_populates="animals",
        lazy="selectin",
    )
```

Now I want to mark both of them as dataclass to have an `__init__` method with typehints. Now my question is if that is a good idea, because both (Base and dataclass) do some “magic” stuff underneath, and I want to know if this could cause any Issues.
Also, the default parameters would now be Column, relationship etc.

Maybe there are other (simpler) options to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Base` when registering dataclasses, it uses the `mapper_registry.mapped` decorator ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/dataclasses.html)):

Here are your classes as declaratively mapped dataclasses, however I corrected the relationships which did not work as you wrote them.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry, relationship

mapper_registry = registry()


@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Person:
    __tablename__ = "persons"  # NOTE: __tablename__ not __table
    __sa_dataclass_metadata_key__ = "sa"
    id: int = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(Integer, primary_key=True)})
    name: str = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(String, nullable=False)})
    age: str | None = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(String)})
    pets: list[Animal] = field(
        default_factory=list,
        metadata={
            "sa": relationship(
                "Animal",
                back_populates="owner",
                lazy="selectin",
            )
        },
    )


@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Animal:
    __tablename__ = "animals"
    __sa_dataclass_metadata_key__ = "sa"
    id: int = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(Integer, primary_key=True)})
    weight: float | None = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(Float)})
    max_age: int | None = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(Integer)})
    owner_id: id = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(ForeignKey("persons.id"))})
    owner: Person = field(
        init=False,
        metadata={
            "sa": relationship(
                "Person",
                back_populates="pets",
                lazy="selectin",
            )
        },
    )
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. Sorry for messing up the __table__ and the relationship, this was not a real example and I just wrote it while asking this question.
Do you think that this is a good solution? I'm just wondering if there is a simpler option to use typehints in the __init__ method...

Comment: Well with that you get both the init and the repr, I haven't really thought of better/worse for mapping a class or mapping a dataclass, use whichever fits your goals.